# PDF file is getting corrupted when sending by HTTP callout to external system

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, apexrest, files

on file upload below function is called in LWC.

LWC Function

```
uploadHelper() {
    this.file = this.filesUploaded[0]; 
    this.fileReader = new FileReader();
    this.fileReader.onloadend = (() => {
        this.fileContents = this.fileReader.result;
        let base64 = 'base64,';
        this.content = this.fileContents.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;
        this.fileContents = this.fileContents.substring(this.content);
            this.saveToSharePoint();
    });

    this.fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
}
```

passed to apex method

```
saveToExternalSystem() {
    sendFile({idParent: this.recordId, strFileName: this.file.name, base64Data: btoa(this.fileContents) })
        .then(result => {
            window.console.log('result ====> ' + result);
            this.showLoadingSpinner = false;
            this.fileName = this.fileName + ' - Uploaded Successfully';
            this.UploadFile = 'File Uploaded Successfully';

        });
}
```

Apex Method -

```
public static Map < String,Object > postFile (Id idParent,String accessToken, 
String strFileName, String base64Data) {
       String file = '\''+strFileName+'\'';
       blob blfile = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
       String body = blfile.toString();
       Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
        req.setHeader('content-length',String.valueof(body.length()));
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken);
        req.setEndpoint(endpointUrl); 
        //req.setBody(body);
        req.setBodyAsBlob(Blob.valueOf(body));
        System.debug('req:--> ' + req);
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
}
```

After this file is successfully getting uploaded, but when i try to open the file it says "file cannot be opened. Try to reload". basically content is getting corrupted.

How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the file through file-reader in JS can be used for a file-size of maximum 716kb. Moreover, you may run in issues like this. I would suggest a different flow:

1. Use standard `fileUpload` with `recordId` as `userId`.
2. After the file(s) are uploaded, when user clicks Done, you get the event `onuploadfinished` which will have information about uploaded `content documents`.
3. In that method, invoke a callout to POST it to external system and appropriate user message can be shown while its processing callout.
4. After callout finishes, delete the document (probably using async apex).

The main advantage of this flow is you can have 2GB limit on file upload and its standard component (have to check limit on callout size)